# I want to create a C# web API for azure speech to text console application

Tags: c#, azure, speech-to-text

I have this following C# console application which uses azure speech to text service and converts speech taken from microphone input into text. I want to create a web API (using the endpoint id, subscription key and service region). Can anyone tell me how to do this?

**C# code**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;

namespace Deployedsample1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string YourSubscriptionKey = "";
        static string YourServiceRegion = "centralindia";
        {
        static void OutputSpeechRecognitionResult(SpeechRecognitionResult 
               speechRecognitionResult)
        {
            switch (speechRecognitionResult.Reason)
        {
            case ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
                Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={speechRecognitionResult.Text}");
                break;
            case ResultReason.NoMatch:
                Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
                break;
            case ResultReason.Canceled:
                var cancellation = CancellationDetails.FromResult(speechRecognitionResult);
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");

                if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails={cancellation.ErrorDetails}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Double check the speech resource key and region.");
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    async static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
       // var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(YourSubscriptionKey, YourServiceRegion);
       
        var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("", "centralindia");
        config.EndpointId = "";
        config.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";
        var reco = new SpeechRecognizer(config);

        //To recognize speech from an audio file, use `FromWavFileInput` instead of `FromDefaultMicrophoneInput`:
        //using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput("YourAudioFile.wav");
        using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
        using var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioConfig);

        Console.WriteLine("Speak into your microphone.");
        var speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
        OutputSpeechRecognitionResult(speechRecognitionResult);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Always remove secrets and keys from the code you post!

Comment: Okay...will make sure of this

Comment: @CSharpRocks can you help me out with web api? if you could send me some references it would be a greate help from you...

Comment: You can refer to [Speech-to-text REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-speech-to-text), [Get a Microsoft Cognitive Services Subscription Key](https://carldesouza.com/get-a-microsoft-cognitive-services-subscription-key/) and [Azure Cognitive Services Speech to Text Hello World in C#](https://carldesouza.com/azure-cognitive-services-speech-to-text-hello-world/)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a web API (using the endpoint id, subscription key
> and service region). Can anyone tell me how to do this?

To achieve the above requirement you can follow the below workaround to achieve it using web api:

```
public class Authentication
{
    public static readonly string FetchTokenUri =
        "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken";
    private string subscriptionKey;
    private string token;

    public Authentication(string subscriptionKey)
    {
        this.subscriptionKey = subscriptionKey;
        this.token = FetchTokenAsync(FetchTokenUri, subscriptionKey).Result;
    }

    public string GetAccessToken()
    {
        return this.token;
    }

    private async Task<string> FetchTokenAsync(string fetchUri, string subscriptionKey)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
            UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(fetchUri);

            var result = await client.PostAsync(uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri, null);
            Console.WriteLine("Token Uri: {0}", uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
            return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

For complete setup please refer this [**`MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-speech-to-text) .